# Python how to perform `re.sub()` on array of strings while retaining splitting points

Tags: python, python-re

I have an array of strings, which represent parts of a paragraph of text with different formatting (you can think of them as HTML `<span>`). I want to perform `re.sub()` on this paragraph while retaining the split points, or in other words, I want to preserve the formatting in this paragraph. How can I do that?

I'll take solutions that does not use `re.sub()` as long as it gets the job done.

For context, this is a demo of what I am trying to do when not concerned with formatting:

```py
import re

def repl(match):
    ix = next(i for i, val in enumerate(match.groups()) if val is not None)
    return f'{match.group(0)} ({keyword_annotate_map[ix]["annotation"]})'

before = 'keyword1 asdafljd asdanfnfg keyword2 snbsbsdbns'

keyword_annotate_map = [
    { 'regex': 'keyword1', 'annotation': 'annotation1' },
    { 'regex': 'keyword2', 'annotation': 'annotation2' }
]

after = re.sub(rf'({")|(".join(re.escape(val["regex"]) for val in keyword_annotate_map)})', repl, before, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(after) # keyword1 (annotation1) asdafljd asdanfnfg keyword2 (annotation2) snbsbsdbns
```

And this is an example input and expected output when concerned with formatting:

```py
# ''.join(before) will return the original string without formatting
before = ['key', 'word1 asdafljd asdanfnfg keyword2 ', 'snbsbsdbns']

# What should the code be here?

print(after) # ['key', 'word1 (annotation1) asdafljd asdanfnfg keyword2 (annotation2) ', 'snbsbsdbns']
```

Comment: You might be able to use `ix = match.lastindex - 1` in `repl()` in place of the iterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add record initial segment sizes, then in each match, check which segment the match is in, and update its size. Then to return to segments, split to the updated sizes.

```python
import re

def split(str, segment_lengths):
    split = []
    for l in segment_lengths:
        split.append(str[:l])
        str = str[l:]
    return split

def annotate(segments, annotation_map={}):
    kwds = list(re.escape(val["regex"]) for val in annotation_map)
    kwd_re = re.compile(rf'({")|(".join(kwds)})', flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    original_segment_lengths = list(map(len,segments))
    annotated_segment_lengths = original_segment_lengths.copy()

    def replace(match):
        kwd = match.lastindex - 1
        annotation = f' ({annotation_map[kwd]["annotation"]})'
        for i,_ in enumerate(original_segment_lengths):
            if match.end() < sum(original_segment_lengths[:i]):
                annotated_segment_lengths[i-1] += len(annotation)
                break
        return f'{match.group()}{annotation}'

    annotated_string = kwd_re.sub(replace, ''.join(segments))
    return split(annotated_string, annotated_segment_lengths)
```

And sample result:

```python
_ANNOTATION_MAP = [
    { 'regex': 'keyword1', 'annotation': 'annotation12' },
    { 'regex': 'keyword2', 'annotation': 'annotation2' },
    { 'regex': 'keyword3', 'annotation': 'annotation3' },
]
test = ['keY', 'word1 asdafljd asdanfnfg keyword2 ', 'snbsbsdbns',
    'KEYWORD1 012345678901234keyword356789', '0123456789']
result = annotate(test, _ANNOTATION_MAP)
print(result)
# ['keY', 'word1 (annotation12) asdafljd asdanfnfg keyword2
# (annotation2) ', 'snbsbsdbns', 'KEYWORD1 (annotation12)
# 012345678901234keyword3 (annotation3)56789', '0123456789']
```

Not optimized at all, so if you're working on really long text you could mark which split the last match was in and start looking there, or change the math to use split positions relative to the joined string length, instead of segment lengths.

Comment: Welp this is certainly an easy way to do it, probably the fastest when optimised as well. How did I not think of it...

Comment: The `re.IGNORECASE` flag needs to be passed as keyword argument `flags=re.IGNORECASE` or its value `2` will be used for the `count` parameter (same issue in the OP)

Comment: `segments` doesn't seem to work correctly as-is; the second segment keeps growing, "swallowing up" subsequent matches (effect can be seen if additional segments are added to `before`).  Maybe an approach working with indices `segments = [sum(segments[:i]) for i, _ in enumerate(segments)]` could work?

Comment: No worries, I will adapt this into my code, fix whatever bug there is, then come back and edit this answer.

Comment: I have taken the fixes from @emno in the comment on the question and this post, and integrated them to fix the bugs pointed out, and done some refactoring for readability. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: @samebertz is very close to the correct answer, just need to replace `for i,_ in enumerate(original_segment_lengths)` with `for i in range(len(original_segment_lengths) + 1)` and replace `if match.end() < sum(original_segment_lengths[:i])` with `if match.end() <= sum(original_segment_lengths[:i])` in `replace(match)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work as an alternative approach to the accepted answer

```
pattern = rf'({")|(".join(re.escape(val["regex"]) for val in keyword_annotate_map)})'

# first do regular substitutions
for i, s in enumerate(before):
    before[i] = re.sub(pattern, repl, s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

# second pass, substitute keywords overlapping adjacent elements
for i, s in enumerate(before):
    if i < 1: continue
    prev = before[i - 1]
    prev_len = len(prev)
    conc = prev + s     # concatenate previous and current element
    for mi in re.finditer(pattern, conc, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        if m := mi:
            if ((m.start() + 1) < prev_len < m.end()):    # check for overlap
                repl_s = re.sub(pattern, repl, conc[m.start():m.end()], 1, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
                before[i] = (conc[:m.start()] + repl_s + conc[m.end():])[prev_len:]
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly this won't work well if you have keywords that are substrings of each other, and you want to match the longer keyword whenever available. Think what would happen if you have the keywords `keyword1 longer` and `keyword1`, and `before = ['keyword1', ' longer', ...]`

Comment: That's true, I didn't think of that. In the accepted answer you can sort the keymap from longer keywords descending to shorter ones which should make it so longer ones are found first.